# What values can the HTML5 aria-label attribute have?

Tags: html

Can someone give me some examples of what type of values are valid for the aria-label attribute.

Answer (score 15):

It can be any string, which is used to name an element. The [ARIA spec: `aria-label`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-label) says:

> Most host languages provide an
>   attribute that could be used to name
>   the element (e.g. the title attribute
>   in HTML), yet this may present a
>   browser tooltip. In the cases where a
>   visible label or visible tooltip is
>   undesirable, authors MAY set the
>   accessible name of the element using
>   aria-label.

So it's like the HTML `title` attribute.

Answer (score 7):

Like Alohci said, it can be a string. Any value you want. You use it like so:

`<input aria-label="This can be anything inside quotes. It can be very long or very short. Can have numbers 1234567890 or symbols !@#$%^&*()-.,<>;/'[]{}\|-_=+å∫ç∂´ƒ©˙ˆ∆˚¬µ˜øπœ®ß†¨√∑≈ÅıÇÎ´Ï˝ÓˆÔÒÂ˜Ø∏Œ‰Íˇ¨◊„˛Á¸">`

Comment: Haha, not that such a label is recommended, of course. [Here’s what that would sound like.](http://cl.ly/3q291t0y3l2v) (And no, I am not under the impression that you are suggesting that authors should insert any special characters possible!)